# Spongy Castle has any Android SDK requirements?

Tags: java, android, bouncycastle, spongycastle

I intend to use [Spongy Castle](https://github.com/rtyley/spongycastle) for my project, but I have a simple doubt about the minimum Android SDK version that I must use.

Also I would like to know if there's any restriction for device capabilities...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SpongyCastle does not include or use any Android-specific features, so there are no Android SDK requirements. Should work on any version. As for devices, there should not be any restrictions, but, obviously, encryption, etc. would work faster on faster (CPU) devices.